# Force Apache HTTP compression event if no Accept-Encoding header was sent?

Tags: apache-2.2, compression

I have a client that sends requests to an apache server (note that the client is not a Web browser and the response is not a Web page). I would like to compress the output (probably with gzip), but I cannot modify the client to send a "Accept-Encoding: gzip" header.

So it is possible to force gzip compression of the response in apache even if no Accept-Encoding header was sent ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do it, but how can you be sure the client will actually understand it? After all, the whole point of the `Accept-Encoding` header is for the client to declare that it understands the encoding.

Comment: This is why I said the client was not a Web browser: i have a unique client of which I know the capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several different ways: you could fake the request header, so gzip works normally, or you could force the DEFLATE output filter onto your content.

To add a request header, look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader

To force gzip output, look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html, which says:

> Note: There is a environment variable force-gzip, set via SetEnv, which
>   will ignore the accept-encoding setting of your browser and will send
>   compressed output.

Plenty of options.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked great with force-gzip !